# Python pool.map seems to freeze randomly when last result is ready

Tags: python, parallel-processing, pool

I have a python3.6 function that does some computation and returns a list of two elements.

```
def my_parallelf(mynumpyarray):
    res = []
    # Do stuff. Append to res
    print("Returning....")
    return res
```

Then I execute this function in parallel, where the different executions take between 10 and 30 minutes like this:

```
p = Pool()
try:
    res = p.map(my_parallelf, points)
except:
    print("Unexpected error:", sys.exc_info()[0])
p.close()
print("Returned!")
```

The strange thing is that the process runs in 75% of the cases correct and in all else the last printed line is "Returning...". Basically the function executes, gets the result and in the moment it should return the last result(I am computing ~ 20 results at a time) it "freezes". No further line is printed. It seems to me that the problem should be somewhere in map, but without an error message I am clueless.

Any help would be appreciated,
T